# how to set usermassdata of dynamic body

Tags: android, andengine

How to set the user mass data of dynamic body in andEngine. My problem is that in my game when i increase the speed of running player, the player on jump cover very long distance with x-axis. This distance changes with the speed. Any solution please..

Comment: Do not post the same question on SO and Gamedev. You can ask mods to migrate the question from there to here if you feel so inclined.

Comment: AndEngine uses Box2D, and I bet the answer is somewhere in [the documentation](http://box2d.org/documentation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting mass data of dynamic body following code can help you.

```
MassData data =  bombBody.getMassData();
data.mass = 10f;
bombBody.setMassData(data);
```